# Data Visualisation Techniques for Multi Labelled data

Tags: data, visualization

I am new to data science and am trying to figure out how to visualize my multi labelled data using graphs. I am using a dataset to classify music by emotion based on their acoustic features (such as: pitch, amplitude etc.).

So some have multi labelled emotion labels.

This is a snapshot of my dataset:

[image: This is a snapshot of my dataset]

Please tell me any techniques for multi label classification visualization techniques. I searched all over the internet, but all of them are related to single label classification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for a Python or R package? Or would a tool like Tableau suffice?

If you feel comfortable using a Python package, seaborn has the ability to visualize multi-label classes.

Take a look at this link: https://towardsdatascience.com/journey-to-the-center-of-multi-label-classification-384c40229bff

Here, there's a good explanation of how to get this done.

However, if you want to use a tool to get your data visualized, look no further than Tableau. However, if you wish to do a lot of machine learning, this wouldn't be a right fit. Else, Tableau can visualize multi-label classification data. All you have to do is plug in your dataset as a data source and navigate to whichever chart preview suits your dataset. Also, Tableau neatly sorts your attributes into dimensions and facts; sometimes erroneously  might I add. In that case, all you have to do is a simple right-click and convert it to a dimension or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

use this link
[blog]: https://github.com/cdpierse/transformers-interpret

Choose MultiLabel Classification Explainer for show the visualize the perforamnce of bert on multiclassification techniques

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).